# How do I add a noindex, nofollow metatag to specific WordPress pages?

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

I would like to stop specific pages from being indexed.

Tried the code below but the `robots` metatag did not show up in the `<header>` section of the page:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
   if ($post->ID == 7407 || $post->ID == 7640 || $post->ID == 7660) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
    }
} );
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable scope issue here: the `$post` object won't be available in your function unless you use the `global` keyword.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    global $post;

    if ($post->ID == 7407 || $post->ID == 7640 || $post->ID == 7660) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />';
    }
} );
```

However, the `$post` object isn't always available: it only gets set when actually viewing a `post`, `page`, or a custom post type. If you try to use this code as is it'll throw some PHP warnings when `$post` isn't set so it might be a better idea to use the [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function instead because the function does this check for you automatically:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    if ( is_page( array(7407, 7640, 7660) ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />';
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using the wp_robots filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'do_nbp_noindex' );

function do_nbp_noindex($robots){
  global $post;
  if(check some stuff based on the $post){
    $robots['noindex'] = true;
    $robots['nofollow'] = true;
  }
  return $robots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of understanding the exact code for noindex nofollow function for single WordPress post:

```
function do_the_noindex($robots){
  global $post;
  if( $post->ID == 26 ) {
    $robots['noindex'] = true;
    $robots['nofollow'] = true;
  }
  return $robots;
}

add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'do_the_noindex' );
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure that the post is "public", while you are publishing it. This code won't work if the post is "Private".

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_noidex_when_sticky($post_id){
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){ 
      return;
    } else{
      if( get_post_meta($post_id, '_property_categories', true ) ){

        //perform other checks
        $status = get_post_meta($post_id, '_property_categories', true );
//        var_dump($status);
//        die;
        //if(is_sticky($post_id)){ -----> this may work only AFTER the post is set to sticky
        if ( $status == 'sell') { //this will work if the post IS BEING SET ticky
            add_action( 'wpseo_saved_postdata', function() use ( $post_id ) {
//                die('test');
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex', '1' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-nofollow', '1' );
            }, 999 );
        }
      }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_noidex_when_sticky' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use $post->ID without using global $post declares outside the loop directly.

```html
<! -- try code it is working fine -->

add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    if(is_page('7407') && get_the_id() == 7407 || is_page('7640') && get_the_id() == 7640 || is_page('7660') && get_the_id() == 7660) {
 // Support Parameters Page ID, title, slug, or array of such to check against.
         echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
     }
});
```